# How do I check that random value equals entered value to input in php on post

Tags: php, variables, post, random, input

I'am new to php and I have no idea why my code in php is always echoing FALSE. 
I do not want to use another hidden input like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="storeRandVal" value="<?php echo $randomValue; ?>
```

to store my generated random value, and then checking if the entered value in input is equal with value that was generated and entered to hidden input. Is there any way around to do it in php also without involving cookies?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$buttonPost = $_POST['button_post']; 
$enteredValue = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['test_input_p']));
$randomValue = rand(1,100);

if(isset($buttonPost))
{
    if($randomValue == $enteredValue)
    {
        echo "TRUE";
    }
    elseif($randomValue != $enteredValue)
    {
        echo "FALSE";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Er__!";
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta></meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="test_input" id="label_input">Enter value: <?php echo $randomValue; ?></label>
                <input id="test_input" name="test_input_p">
                <input type="submit" id="ibutton_send" name="button_post" value="Send">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even though it's hidden, you still have to echo - `value="<?php echo $randomValue; ?>` - Plus, remove the `</input>` it's not needed, so do `<input type="hidden" name="storeRandVal" value="<?php echo $randomValue; ?>`

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your goals, but if Random numbers we are talking about, why not generating the number only after the user posted his number? by that you don't have to store any value.

Comment: Ok I forgot about echo inside of it ;) Ok and I will remove all </input>'s

Comment: For example in the future I want to make him to see two random numbers and tell him that he should add the two random numbers together and enter the correct answer - that will load another page or something.

Comment: I've posted something for you below. @junky Sessions are not required, not for a single page. More than 2 pages, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not store the random value in a session? Re-set the session only when a form is not submitted (eg; when a user comes to this page from a different page)

Comment: And what when the user will refresh the current site?

Comment: A "normal" refresh (Not re-submitting the form) will work just like coming to this page from somewhere else. Re-submitting the form will obviously create more problems, which is why the best method is using the hidden input field.

Comment: I see that I am forced to use hidden input field then ;P

Comment: Yup :) There's more than one approach to this problem, but some of them can get pretty complicated... So yeah, use the hidden input field. :)

Comment: And what kind of problems - like what key words should I use in google to find such a problems in php?

Comment: Technically you could also count the amount of forms submitted with a session ($_SESSION["forms_submitted"]++), and if it's bigger than 1, then generate a new random value, but yeah... It's quite an annoying solution for such a minor problem. I recommend you skip this problem and use a hidden text field :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Fred commented, you **have** to include the hidden input. By its nature, PHP's `rand()` [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) gives you a different answer every time you load the page.

You'll need to compare the `$_POST['test_input_p']` and `$_POST['storeRandVal']` values in order to confirm that the user entered the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

Store the hidden value in a variable then compare it with that value.

(Unless you will be using this for more than 2 pages, sessions are not needed, not for this since you're using your entire code inside the same page.)

```
<?php
$buttonPost = $_POST['button_post']; 
$enteredValue = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['test_input_p']));

$hidden = $_POST['storeRandVal'];
$randomValue = rand(1,100);

if(isset($buttonPost))
{

    if($enteredValue == $hidden)
    {
        echo "TRUE";
    }
    elseif($randomValue != $hidden)
    {
        echo "FALSE";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Er__!";
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta></meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="storeRandVal" value="<?php echo $randomValue; ?>">

            <fieldset>
                <label for="test_input" id="label_input">Enter value: <?php echo $randomValue; ?></label>
                <input id="test_input" name="test_input_p">
                <input type="submit" id="ibutton_send" name="button_post" value="Send"></input>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried to avoid hidden input, but I see that there is no other option as for single page.

Comment: @junky You're welcome. However I'm curious, why not a hidden input? Wait, I think I know; the number will appear in the HTML source. Unless you have another reason?